# Adding Line Segments to xaml dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem with visualizing a path which contains multiple line segments on a canvas.

Right now a user can connect two controls on canvas with a direct path. This is done by creating an instance of a viewmodel class which is passed to a templateselector which returns the datatemplate for a path.

This template looks like

```
<Path StrokeThickness="2"
          Stroke="Black"
          Fill="Black"
          MinWidth="1"
          MinHeight="1"
          Name="arrowPath">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigureCollection>
                        <PathFigure IsClosed="False"
                                    StartPoint="{Binding Path=Source, ElementName=_this}">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <LineSegment IsStroked="True"
                                                 Point="{Binding Path=Destination, ElementName=_this}" />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                        <PathFigure IsClosed="True"
                                    IsFilled="True"
                                    StartPoint="{Binding Path=Destination, ElementName=_this}">
                            <PathFigure.Segments>
                                <PathSegmentCollection>
                                    <LineSegment IsSmoothJoin="True"
                                                 IsStroked="True"
                                                 Point="{Binding Path=TrianglePoint2, ElementName=_this}" />
                                    <LineSegment IsSmoothJoin="True"
                                                 IsStroked="True"
                                                 Point="{Binding Path=TrianglePoint3, ElementName=_this}" />
                                </PathSegmentCollection>
                            </PathFigure.Segments>
                        </PathFigure>
                    </PathFigureCollection>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

The Start- and EndPoint Attributes of the Path are bound to properties of the viewmodel instance.

Everythings working fine so far. But with more Controls the canvas is really a mess and i want to give the user the opportunity to connect controls via paths consisting of multiple line segments. The new viewmodel class stores the mouseposition(s) when clicked in a List.

Designing the new Control I cannot figure out how to dynamically add a LineSegment in my xaml for each Point in my List.

I hope you understand what I mean, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part), it contains a step-by-step tutorial on creating a diagram designer, including [orthogonal connector routing](http://ww2.cs.mu.oz.au/~pjs/papers/gd09.pdf) and how to model them in the UI.